# Overload parent class method with input of interface with child class method with input of child class

Tags: java, overloading

I am trying to overload a method of a parent class with a more specific child class. Here is the example code.

```
interface A {
   public void test(A o);
}

abstract class B implements A {
   public void test(A o) {
      System.out.println("Different");
   }
}
class C extends B {
   public void test(C o) {
      System.out.println("C");
   }
}
class D extends B {
   public voit test(D o) {
      System.out.println("D");
   }
}
```

What I want when I run `new C().test(new C())` for it to print "C", not to print "Different", but when I run it with any other class for it to print "Different". Is there a way for this to work? Or do I need to overload the method with methods with input for each class inside each class?

Comment: May you clarify what is the issue you are having? When I run your code I have your desired behavior with C. If you want the class D to print different you should not overload the method? Maybe an expected output and the associated line you are running to get it will help.

Comment: A class can't extend itself. Please show your actual code.

Comment: @RichardKYu, actually I believe it works for me as well. I am a student and this is the essence of the code I was writing. It was only returning an error when I was submitting it for the class. Maybe it has to do with the way they are testing the code or something. Thank you for the help.

Comment: The method to call is resolved at compile time, so you will get different results if you call `new C().test(new C())` versus `A c = new C(); new C().test(c)`. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: (In the latter case, the *object* is actually a `C`, but the *declared type* is `A` (which is okay, because a C **is-a** A), and the compiler will call the test method in `B`.)